# Cannot push commits to the Branch

Tags: visual-studio-2017, synchronization, bitbucket, commit

I did some version changes in my project and commit those. But I cannot Sync those and push to the server. SO that I cannot make a pull request in bitbucket?

I am using Visual studio 2017

It Shows the error message"Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details."

In the out window, it display "One of your commit messages is missing a valid issue key:"

Can any one please help me? I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error message is:

> One of your commit messages is missing a valid issue key:

Most likely, this is being caused by either a client or server side Git hook.  The fix here is probably to check the commits you have made since last pulling the branch, and verify that each one has an issue key/number.

As to *why* the Git hook is ensuring that each commit has an issue key, it is to ensure that your commit history can easily be correlated with your team's issue tracker tool (such as Jira or Trello).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my above problem.
In there it displayed a Error message called "One of your commit messages is missing a valid issue key".

For solve this I click on my current working branch and go to "View History". Then you can see all the commit messages and your branch history in Visual Studio.

Then you should identify which commit have the issue. Some times it may be a space in your gira task id.

Then double click on the comment that have the issue.If it is your lastly updated commit then you can directly edit that commit message and click on "ammend message".Then your commit is again in the changes tab in your Visual studio.

If it is not your lastly update commit then you have to click on the "Reset" "Reset and keep changes" and refresh your history tab in your visual studio until the issue comment become the first. Then you can edit the commit message and "ammend" it.